# Meteor, call js after template has changed

Tags: templates, meteor, var

I have a meteor template.
This templates servers as a "code widged"

```
// Mockup code:
If Enabled.get() == false:
    // a code spoiler buttons should be loaded.

If Enabled.get() == true:
    // an ace editor instance should be loaded.
    // so i have to wait until the div is rendered 
    // that i can set the div as the ace target.
```

So it should be reactive on a template variable.
AND i need the rendered DOM for replaceing the div with ace.

How would i do this in meteor templates?
I've tried several ways, atm i've used a workaround with 
a button click event and setTimeout....

I' have a feeling that i have to do this with "onRendered"
But it seems that onRendered gets not called when i just change a template variable...
Maybe i could go with afterflush? 
I'm a little confused to be honest...

Template:

```
<template name="msgMultiline">
        <button class="ui black inverted button" data-command="enable">CODE SPOILER</button>  
        {{#if Enabled}}
          <br>
          <div data-control="acetarget" id="{{_id}}" style="width:300px; height:100px">{{msg}}</div>
        {{/if}}
    </template>
```

Template Helpers/Events:

```
Template.msgMultiline.helpers({
    Enabled() {return Template.instance().Enabled.get()}
})

Template.msgMultiline.onCreated(function () {
    this.Enabled = new ReactiveVar(false);
});

Template.msgMultiline.events({
    'click [data-command="enable"]' (event,instance) {
        instance.Enabled.set(!(instance.Enabled.get()));
        console.log("events: " + self.Enabled.get())
        if (self.Enabled.get() == true){
            console.log("Should Create ACE "+ this._id)
        }
    }

})
```

Answer (score 0):

I've got it.
To run javascript code when the view has changed i'd to write:

```
Template.msgMultiline.events({
    'click [data-command="enable"]' (event,instance) {
        instance.Enabled.set(!(instance.Enabled.get()));
        if (instance.Enabled.get() == true){
            var MYID = instance.data._id; //debug

        Tracker.afterFlush(function () {
            AceEditor.instance(MYID) // test
            ace.edit(MYID)  // test
        })

        }
    }
})
```